# Uso de Trait em método estático

Tags: php, métodos-estáticos, trait

Considerando o exemplo abaixo, de que forma é possível utilizar o método da `Trait` dentro do método `static` da classe?

1. É possível? Como?
2. É uma má prática? Qual a forma correta?

   ```
   trait TestTraits
   {
       public function thistraitmethod($data)
       {
          return $data;
       }
   }


   class ClassUsingTrait
   {
       use TestTraits;

       public static function staticmethod($data)
       {
           return $this->thistraitmethod($data);
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isto não é possível pela simples razão que `$this` não existe neste contexto. Um método estático está no contexto da classe, e não da instância. Qual `$this` ele vai pegar? Será que existe algum? É impossível usar qualquer membro de instância dentro de um método estático. O problema não é o `trait` em si, só uma consequência do que ele faz, por isso vale para tudo que mude de contexto desta forma.

O contrário é possível, instâncias podem acessar membros estáticos já que existe uma e somente uma instância dele.

É possível fazer assim:

```
trait TestTraits {
    public function thistraitmethod($data) {
       return $data;
    }
}

class ClassUsingTrait {
    use TestTraits;
    public static function staticmethod(ClassUsingTrait $objeto, $data) {
        return $objeto->thistraitmethod($data);
    }
}

$x = new ClassUsingTrait();
ClassUsingTrait::staticmethod($x, "xxx");
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/kUqotR). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/wzjtupgu-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/TraitStaticMethod.php).